# Porque el input text se sale del form y el input select no?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando que el input text ocupe todo el ancho del formulario poniendo `width: 100%` pero se sale, asi que puse 99% en vez de 100%, el problema es que al hacer eso el input select, ya no ocupa todo el ancho:

**Asi me aparece:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo html:**

```
<head>
    <title>Encuesta Sobre Deporte </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>    
    <header>
    <h1 id="title">Encuesta Sobre Deporte</h1>
    <p id="description">Los datos recolectados no seran utilizados en tu contra<p>
    </header>

    <form id="survey-form">
        <label id="name-label" class="item">Nombre: <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..." required/></label>
        <label id="email-label" class="item">Correo electronico: <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo electronico..." required/></label>
        <label id="number-label" class="item">Edad: <input type="number" id="number" min="13" max="80" placeholder="Edad..." required/></label>
        <label> Cual es tu deporte favorito?
            <select id="dropdown" class="item">
                <option value=""> Cual es tu deporte favorito?</option>
                <option value="1"></option>
                <option value="2"></option>
                <option value="3"></option>
            </select>
        </label>
    <form>
</body>
```

**Archivo css:**

```
body{
    font-family: Cambria;
    margin: auto;        
    background-image: url(https://deporteypelolargo.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/cropped-befunky_tilt-shift_2.jpg);        
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

/*Formulario dondo va todo*/
form{
    background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 60%);    
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*los items*/
input,
select
{      
    width: 100%;
}

label
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Quiero que el input text y el input select ocupen todo el ancho sin tener que modificar el ancho individualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo, en primera instancia cuando haremos configuraciones y diseños con CSS, es recomendable hacer unas configuraciones previas.

El siguiente código indica que todo lo que podamos hacer en el HTML, el padding no exista, el margin no exista, y todas las cajas cumplan con la proporción exacta:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Coloca ese pedazo de código antes del diseño aplicado al body, y quita la propiedad margin:auto aplicada en el body.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Excelente, me alegra haber ayudado!